# Example of a set for which none of the limit points are in the set?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Is there any example of a set for which none of the limit points are in the set ?
I can't think of such set right now.

Comment: This was trivial.

Answer (score 1):

$$\left\{\frac1n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}$$

Answer (score 1):

The set $\{1, 1/2, 1/3, ...\}$ has $0$ as its only limit point. Alternatively, if $a_n$ is a sequence monotonically tending to $a$, but $a_n \neq a$ for all $n$, then $\{a_n\}$ will have a unique limit point at $a$ not lying in the set.

Answer (score 0):

$$\Large{\emptyset}$$

*Explanation*. Let $X$ be a subset of our topological space and $Y$ be the set of its limit points. The statement "none of the elements of $Y$ are elements of $X$" translates as $\neg(\exists y\in Y,y\in X)$--if my translation is incorrect, please correct me in the comments--which is equivalent to $\forall y\in Y,y\not\in X$. In the case $Y=\emptyset$, which holds when $X$ is empty, the claim is a vacuous truth.

Comment: What is the closure of the empty set? I believe it is the empty set. In particular, it has no limit points so all its limit points are its members.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I edited my answer with an elaboration of why I believe $\emptyset$ works. Your statement reads as $\forall x\in Y,x\in X$. Its negation is $\exists x\in Y,x\not\in X$, which is not how I would interpret "none of the elements of $Y$ are in $X$".

Comment: Karl, I figured that much from your previous comment (now deleted), I still feel that this is an almost a misinterpretation of the question, though. Also, I didn't vote your answer (neither up nor down).

Comment: @AsafKaragila Ah, I had only guessed you were the downvoter, sorry.

Comment: I can understand why, it's fine. But it wasn't me.